# declaring an array type of custom object to a typescript function

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I hae a model of car imported into current component. Trying to declare an array of cars as a return type to one of the functions. But the compiler would not recognize the car array type. Can you please help ?

carcomponent.ts

```
     import  { Car } from '../models/car';

     export class carComponent implements onInit {
        public car : Car;

        carsavailable(): Car[] { //delcaring Car[] is not recognized.

        }

     }
```

car.ts
.......

```
     export class Car {
          name: string;
     }
```

ERROR

The compiler underlines Car[] in red and says 'A function whose delcared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Do I have to plug in car somewhere or change return type declaration way.

Comment: It does seem to recognise the type, it just bitches about your implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a method with a return type so it should be returning a value

```
carsavailable(): Car[] { 
     return [];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are not returning any value from the function so that compiler is showing the error

```
carsavailable(): Car[] { //delcaring Car[] is not recognized.
    return [];
  }
```